# Only allow two decimal places on number input?

Tags: html, validation, input

Is there a way with `<input type="number">` to only allow up to two decimal places? I've seen that you can limit the max character cound and the step, but it doesn't seem there is a way to only allow two decimals.

Even with `<input type="number" step="0.01">` the input will still allow `3.3532` instead of maxing out at `3.35`

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: @bcr Definitely not a duplicate, that will still allow you to manually type in more than 2 decimals.

Comment: @bcr yeah, it's not a duplicate. The OP has asked about different phenomenon

Comment: Does it have to be pure html or you can use jquery?

Comment: @JoeScotto Use javascript instead or you want a pure html solution??

Comment: Javascript would be easy to do but HTML would be best, I don't understand why there isn't just a `maxlength` attribute for a number input, it makes no sense in my opinion.

Comment: If you don't want js, try to use use two inputs, one for the number and one for the decimal.